# Change Clock: Add dd.mm (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, clock

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.

Now I would like to change the clock looks.

Up to now it looks like this:

[image]

I would like to see dd.mm to see the date of today.

How to do this?

Comment: If you use gnome, you can install Gnome Shell Extension DateTime Format (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1173/datetime-format/), and setup the format of date & time.

Comment: didn't you try `clock ovverride` extension??

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` adds an extension/alternative to the default desktop editor. One such option is exactly what you want, changing the information/appearance of the clock. Once installed, just search for "tweaks", or run `sudo gnome-tweaks` from the command line.